# php: datetime arithmetic

Tags: php, datetime

I'm a bit stuck with the `DateInterval` class of PHP.  What I really want is the number of seconds elapsed between two `DateTime` stamps.

```
$t1 = new DateTime( "20100101T1200" );
$t2 = new DateTime( "20100101T1201" );
// number of seconds between t1 and t2 should be 60

echo "difference in seconds: ".$t1->diff($t2)->format("%s");
```

Yet all I get is zero.  Is the `DateInterval` class not suited for arithmetic?  How *can* I get the 'exact' number of seconds (or hours, or whatever) between two time stamps?

Comment: I would like to see how you get the exact number anything above days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the seconds quickly you might aswell use

```
$diff = abs($t1->getTimestamp() - $t2->getTimestamp());
```

Your code returns 0, because the actual **seconds** difference is 0, the difference in your example is **1 minute** (1 minute, 0 seconds). If you print the *%i* format, you will get 1, which is the correct diff of `$t1` and `$t2`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was so happy with the type-safe `DateInterval`: you can't add anything but that to a `DateTime`, which is great.  But this does the trick.  (And on PHP 5.2, you can use `DateTime::format("U")` to retrieve the number of seconds since the epoch)

Comment: Glad to help and I'm very happy to see people using PHP 5.3 in production :)